# Animating UIViews to get crossfade effect not working very well

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, uideviceorientation

I have successfully created a icon menu that displays from a tabBar selection. You can view this menu in either Portrait or Landscape.

because of the space on the screen I have made it so that in portrait you can view 4x4 icons.. however due to sizing when viewed in landscape this dose not work that well.. so I have made it so that you can view 2 rows of 6 and 1 row of 4. because of this, I have decided to create two UIViews for the menu, when the device rotates I switch between the two views.

i.e. if Portrait current and device is rotated load Landscape and unload Portrait and vice versa.

This is the code I am using to change views on the device rotation, this works perfectly fine (might not be the best code but its the best I could do)

```
if  ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            if([jumpBarContainerLandscape superview])
            {
            // Device is changing from landscape to protrait change views to fit
            // load landscape view
            jumpBarContainerPortrait = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (367 - jumpBarHeightPortrait), 320.0, (jumpBarHeightPortrait + 49.0))];
            jumpBarContainerPortrait.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
            jumpBarContainerPortrait.alpha = 0.0;

            // add jumpbar container to view
            [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                             animations:^{

                                 jumpBarContainerLandscape.alpha = 0.0;


                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 if (finished) {


                                 }
                             }];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                             animations:^{

                                 jumpBarContainerPortrait.alpha = 1.0;


                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 if (finished) {

                                     // remove subView for superView
                                     [jumpBarContainerLandscape removeFromSuperview];
                                 }
                             }];

            }
        }
        else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            if ([jumpBarContainerPortrait superview])
            {
            // Device is changing from portrait to landscape change views to fit
            // load landscape view
            jumpBarContainerLandscape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (207 - jumpBarHeightLandscape), 480.0,  (jumpBarHeightLandscape + 49.0))];
            jumpBarContainerLandscape.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
            jumpBarContainerLandscape.alpha = 0.0;

            // add jumpbar container to view
            [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerLandscape belowSubview:actionTabBar];


                // fade out
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                             animations:^{

                                 jumpBarContainerPortrait.alpha = 0.0;


                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 if (finished) {


                                 }
                             }];

               // fade in
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                             animations:^{


                                 jumpBarContainerLandscape.alpha = 1.0;


                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 if (finished) {

                                     // remove subView for superView
                                     [jumpBarContainerPortrait removeFromSuperview];
                                 }
                             }];
            }
        }
```

Now the issue I am having is that the animation between the two UIViews is quite ugly, its not very smooth you can see the two different views on the animation etc which is undesirable.. I was wondering if anyone could think of a nice way to crossfade between the two making it look abit smoother etc...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

So I have just tried to  create a CATransaction, however I have an error on one line giving me this error **No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'jumpBarContainerPortrait'**  I have added a comment to the line where I get this error below.. any help would be appreciated

```
[CATransaction begin];
            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
            animation.duration = 3.50;

            [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];

            [[self.view jumpBarContainerPortrait] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Fade"]; // Error is happening here!
            [CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Have you tried using `CATransition` instead with type `kCATransitionFade`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of your separate fade in and fade out animations, use the UIView method "transitionFromView".  Here's an example:

```
        [UIView transitionFromView:jumpBarContainerLandscape
                            toView:jumpBarContainerPortrait
                          duration:crossDissolveTime 
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                        completion:NULL];
```

Comment: cool thanks, this is kind of working.. its doing weird things with the tab bar, even though I am inserting jumpBarContainerPortrait behind my tabBar the view appears over the tab bar after the transition has happened... so just trying to figure that out now.

Comment: yea turns out it gives slightly worse results that the animation I had.. I dont know why but it fades my tabbar out as well ... which is weird, its a nice solution but it didnt do anything for my animation, so I will keep this thread open and see if anyone else has suggestions.. if not then I guess I will mark yours as correct.